# QWidget not closing - leaving empty window

Tags: qt, events, qwidget

I have a problem with a `QWidget` derivate (`NewPayment`). It's a simple window, with some controls and a `QDialogButtonBox` . It has 2 slots:

```
void NewPayment::on_buttonBox_accepted() {
    //(some action going in here)
    this->close();
} 

void NewPayment::on_buttonBox_rejected() {
    this->close();
}
```

When I click either OK or Cancel - the slot is triggered as expected. The problem is, that the window **does not close**. All the contents dissappears, and an empty window is left (window title is left).

The widget exists as a MDISubwindow, and is created like so:

```
void HurBudClientGUI::addNewPayment(int direction, int contractorid) {
    foreach(QMdiSubWindow* it, this->ui.mainArea->subWindowList()) {
        if ( NewPayment* np = qobject_cast<NewPayment*>( it->widget() )  ) {
            if (np->getContractorID() == contractorid) {
                this->ui.mainArea->setActiveSubWindow(it);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    NewPayment* np = new NewPayment(direction, contractorid, this);
    np->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    this->ui.mainArea->addSubWindow(np);
    np->show();
}
```

The interesting part is, that when I either:

- click on the 'X' in tre upper right corner
- call `QMdiArea::closeActiveSubWindow()` from the main window
- call `QMdiArea::closeAllSubWindows()` from the main window

the window is closed properly. I have overwritten a `QWidget::closeEvent(QCloseEvent * event)` for my class:

```
void NewPayment::closeEvent(QCloseEvent * event) {
    qDebug() << "[" << __FUNCTION__ << "]:" << "event: " << event  << "; sender:" << sender();
}
```

and it shows preety much the same event every time - no matter how I try to close it:

```
[ NewPayment::closeEvent ]: event:  QCloseEvent(Close, 0x40bd64, type = 19) ; sender: QDialogButtonBox(0x4dfa7a8, name = "buttonBox") // I hit cancel
[ NewPayment::closeEvent ]: event:  QCloseEvent(Close, 0x40b634, type = 19) ; sender: QObject(0x0) // I hit the 'X' in the window corner
[ NewPayment::closeEvent ]: event:  QCloseEvent(Close, 0x40b468, type = 19) ; sender: QObject(0x0) // I hit "close active sub window" from parent window
[ NewPayment::closeEvent ]: event:  QCloseEvent(Close, 0x40b454, type = 19) ; sender: QObject(0x0)  // I hit "close all sub windows" from parent window
```

The best part is, that when I hit "cancel" (the windows is cleared, but stays open), and then click "X" or whatever - the window is closed, but the control does not pass through my `NewPayment::closeEvent` (i have a brakepoint there - and it does not fire) .

It works preety much the same in other windows. What is strange, that I'm preety sure that it worked previously (+- a week ago) for other windows (they closed after clicking OK ant performing all necessary operations) . I guess I will end up analyzyig diff from SVN, but maybe someone had similar issue? I have had very little sleep lately, so maybe I missed something trivial?

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed @ddriver 's suggestion and ended up with

```
void NewPayment::on_buttonBox_rejected() {
    if (QMdiSubWindow* psw = qobject_cast<QMdiSubWindow*>(this->parent()) ) {
        psw->close();
    } else {
        this->close();
    }
}
```

Now it works as it was supposed to.

Answer (score 2):

What do you expect, a widget is not a window. You get output from closing the widget, but that's not the same as closing the window.

You need to have a handle to the window if you want to close it. You could:

- keep the pointer returned from `addSubWindow()`
- create the window in advance, create the widget parented to the window, set the window's widget to the widget, and then use the widget's `parent()` to access the window.

Comment: thanks. I followed your way, and achieved what I needed